# print with f-string formatting on float - unable to get how the output is generated

Tags: python, formatting, f-string

```
x = 100.1205
y = str(x)[6]
```

which means y=0

When try to execute below code output is 100.

```
print ("{:.{}f}".format(x,y))
```

Can anyone tell how it is giving 100 as output.

Comment: What are you expecting as the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, let's number the fields: the format string `'{:.{}f}'` is equivalent to `'{0:.{1}f}'`.

The argument at position 1 is `y`, which equals 0, so this is equivalent to `'{0:.0f}'` by substitution. That is, it formats the argument at position 0 (i.e. `x`) as a float, with 0 decimal places.

So, the result is `'100'`, because that's `x` to 0 decimal places. You can try this with different values of `y` to see the results:

```py
>>> '{:.{}f}'.format(100.1205, 0)
'100'
>>> '{:.{}f}'.format(100.1205, 1)
'100.1'
>>> '{:.{}f}'.format(100.1205, 2)
'100.12'
>>> '{:.{}f}'.format(100.1205, 3)
'100.121'
>>> '{:.{}f}'.format(100.1205, 4)
'100.1205'
>>> '{:.{}f}'.format(100.1205, 5)
'100.12050'
```

Answer (score 0):

The curly braces are being interpreted from the outside in, i.e. the outer-most braces will be replaced with the first argument of `format()`, i.e `x`, while the inner-most braces will be replaced with the second argument of `format()`, i.e. `y`. Here, `x` will represent the float to display, and y will represent the significant digits after the decimal place. See plenty of examples and docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html?highlight=string%20format#format-examples)

If this is still unclear, I would break it down into single format operation first, to better understand:

```
>>> print ("{}".format(x))
100.1205
```

Now all we want to do is trim off all significant digits after the decimal point, then:

```
>>> print ("{:.0f}".format(x))
100
```

Or to trim off all but one:

```
>>> print ("{:.1f}".format(x))
100.1
```

Adding another parameter to `format()`, i.e. y, then allows you to modify the significant digits with the value of y.

```
>>> print ("{:.{}f}".format(x,y)
100
```

Answer (score 0):

`x = 100.1205, y = str(x)[6`]. here `y = 0`

first of all understand the `"{:.{}f}".format(x,y)`. here we are using the position formatting of the string . then we can see that x is at position 0 and y is at position 1.

we can consider `"{:.{}f}"` it as "`{value of x:{value of y}f}`"

now value of x is 100 and value of y is 0 so the string will look like
"{100:.{0}f}". that means that there is 0  or no digits after decimal

when `print("{:.{}f}".format(x,y))` will execute it will print "100"